# Google Forms - Checkboxes - Edit Option

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

I've got a google form with a checkboxes question: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ngHnWZlyZQ3RirL7X4rHj8_x9gLa_CvVyPiyLkUmQls/viewform

I edited an option (to clarify it), and now the number of respondents who ticked that option has been reset to zero.  I've tried a search and replace on the responses spreadsheet, but the summary still shows zero.

Can I do something so that the old responses are counted in the summary?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to open up the spreadsheet where the results are stored, and make your own manual summary.    I don't think that Forms automatic summary can cope with this in any way.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be reset to previous value. Try making a copy of the Spreadsheet and reverting your Spreadsheet to an older version using Revision History. Try at your own risk!
You won't lose data for sure.

Comment: not quite what i want, but a useful idea.  there's no way to revert the form is there?  if i won't lose data, what is the risk?

Comment: No There isn't any way to reset the form. I was afraid it might screw up your form in some way & you'll lose all your response summary. So I asked to make a copy & try.